# Accidentally modified an iOS SDK header file, now I cannot compile in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I don't know how I modified a iOS SDK file, but Xcode say I did.  Here is what they reported.

```
fatal error: file '/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIFontDescriptor.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users/m/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/24CDWDK5BTYJE/UIKit.pcm' was built
note: after modifying system headers, please delete the module cache at '/Users/m/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/24CDWDK5BTYJE'
1 error generated.
```

I tried to look for this DerivedData but could not. I also went into organizer to delete it and did a clean, even after that, no luck.

How do I restore this UIFontDescriptor.h to its original form?

Comment: UPdate: I went into the MOduleCache and deleted EVERYTHING, then re-cleaned again, and now it will compile in simulator.

Comment: Yeah the modules thing isn't fully ironed out yet - you can disable it in the project settings if it becomes a major issue.

Comment: I have wondered about how you would fix this too. But maybe more importantly, why are you allowed to modify header files from the SDK? Didn't use to be able to modify these files in the old days.

Comment: got to UIFontDescriptor.h and undo the  changes .

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Remove the pcm file

> rm
>   "/Users/m/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/24CDWDK5BTYJE/UIKit.pcm"

then

> Clean Project( Cmd+Shift+K)

**Problem solved**

Comment: I went to the following folder [Shift+Cmnd+G] and searched for `UIKit.pcm` and deleted all of them! `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/`. 

Thanks for answer, this works best guys!

Comment: The identifier may be different, but it can be determined by looking at the exact Xcode errors.

Comment: FWIW, I had to delete the parent folder (24CDWDK5BTYJE/ above) and then do a Clean to get it to work:

    rm -rf 24CDWDK5BTYJE/

Answer (score 15):

I fixed this by deleting the entire contents of the ModuleCache folder:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/*
```

Comment: this removed all of my project data from desktop.. everything.. damn

Comment: You probably didn't cd into the proper directory. Make sure you replace the 'you' above with your Mac OS username.

Comment: Your answer is potentially danger. Can you fix it? Like this: `cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/ && rm -rf ./*` or like this: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/*`

Comment: @JamieForrest You are my hero

Comment: @k06a It Helped.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Cmd + Shift + K

Cleans the project and should fix any "accidentally touched" framework files.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by delete derived data. It work for me.

Step 1: In Xcode goto Window->Projects select your project and press delete button next to Derived data.

Step 2: Clean the project (Cmd + shift + K)

Comment: For what it's worth, I was having this problem trying to use the PubNub framework via CocoaPods. Xcode wasn't recognizing the PubNub framework when I tried to import it. Deleting the derived data fixed this. This is under Window->Projects, not Window->Organizer->Projects.

Answer (score 0):

While building your app it will show the errors right.Go to the error description and it will show the path to delete the cache files.select the path and go that folder in folder options and then delete the cache.clean the project and build it.run the app it will run successfully

Answer (score 0):

First Clean Your project SHIFT+CMD+K or direct from product menu.

If that doesn't help, delete the derived data. 
1. First go to Xcode.
2. go to Preference.
3. Tap on Locations.
4. Tap on -> above the path of Derived Data It will redirect to folder in finder.
5. Delete that Derived Data Folder.

It is working for me.